# Why is SharePoint 2010 looking for en-us and not en-gb with resource files?

Tags: 2010, language, resource-files

> Failed to read resource file "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\Resources\RegistrationResource.en-US.resx" from feature
>   id "(null)".

I am getting loads of errors implying im using en-US but I have set it to use United Kingdom in the site settings.

I have even resorted to trying a SQL query on the  Webs table.

```
UPDATE dbo.Webs SET Language = 2057
```

Am I missing something? How do I update my whole SharePoint system to us EN-GB?

The errors occur on a page where I am not logged in (registration page) and I'm curious as the error message mentions a feature id so thinking it is related to the web parts possibly but I'm a bit stuck with this one.

Where does this need updating to ensure the whole systems default is en-gb?

NOTE:
Everything seems to work fine, but these error messages are frequent. Is this actually going to be an issue??

A link I found during research is below. Does anyone know if this is true of SharePoint 2010 still?

http://www.astaticstate.com/2009/10/sharepoint-gb-2057-localization.html

Comment: Never directly set any properties on any of the SQL tables in the database. Doing so renders your environment unsupportable.

Comment: Yes I know it does, this is just on a test box I was running out of options and wanted to see if it would work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What was the install language of the WFE?

Comment: How can I check this? I didn't do the initial install

Comment: It'll be whatever locale is set up on the OS on the server itself.

Comment: How did you solve this problem, Do you feel this is related? --->   http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95898/webpart-cannot-be-seen-on-page-after-adding-error-in-uls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default language for a *whole* SharePoint system is based on the installation language of original SharePoint installation media and cannot be changed (without a re-install). With additional language packs, site collections can be created in a selection of languages, but once again, once the site collection has been created, the default language cannot be changed. However, from a SharePoint language setting there is no difference between en-US and en-GB, it is just English. The US or GB distinction is a culture distinction, not a language setting. I don't believe that there is a separate SharePoint installation for en-GB than en-US for example.

If you have custom features/code that includes localization for multiple languages, depending on how the code was written, it may either be looking for the client browser language setting, or the language setting of the site collection or the language setting of the user preference for site language setting (if site collection is configured to support alternate languages and allow the user to select language from the user settings menu).

When writing localization code, developers have a choice whether to localize just to the overall language (e.g. en) which is culturally neutral, or to a specific cultural variation (e.g. en-US). The code will first look for a resource file specific to language and culture, then for a culture neutral if available, then to a default.

Long story short - this is probably an issue with how a feature was localized than an issue with the site collection default language, particularly if the issue is related to a cultural variation like en-US vs en-GB.