# Webpart cannot be seen on page after adding. Error in ULS. Feature (wsp) = Webpart+ListInstance

Tags: 2013, web-part, error, uls

Need some help on this one.

We have deployed a webpart on LIVE server. On test server it worked fine.

Now on LIVE we cannot see the webpart after adding to page. ULS:

> Failed to open the file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Template\Features\MyWebPart_MyPart
>   WebPart\Resources\Resources.en-US.resx'.  5be2859c-93a0-e0a4-d8bc-bbc416633918
>
> The specified path "" does not
>   exist.    5be2859c-93a0-e0a4-d8bc-bbc416633918
>
> Failed to read resource file "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Template\Features\MyWebPart_MyPart
>   WebPart\Resources\Resources.en-US.resx" from feature id
>   "ef587aa8-2178-4c7c-9f4d-38c3c94aefdc".   5be2859c-93a0-e0a4-d8bc-bbc416633918
>
> Failed to open the language resource for
>   Feaef587aa8-2178-4c7c-9f4d-38c3c94aefdc keyfile
>   Resources.    5be2859c-93a0-e0a4-d8bc-bbc416633918
>
> Failed to open the file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Template\Features\MyWebPart_MyPart
>   WebPart\Resources\Resources.resx'.    5be2859c-93a0-e0a4-d8bc-bbc416633918
>
> The specified path "" does not
>   exist.    5be2859c-93a0-e0a4-d8bc-bbc416633918
>
> Failed to read resource file "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Template\Features\MyWebPart_MyPart
>   WebPart\Resources\Resources.resx" from feature id
>   "ef587aa8-2178-4c7c-9f4d-38c3c94aefdc".   5be2859c-93a0-e0a4-d8bc-bbc416633918
>
> Failed to open the language resource for
>   Feaef587aa8-2178-4c7c-9f4d-38c3c94aefdc keyfile
>   Resources.    5be2859c-93a0-e0a4-d8bc-bbc416633918
>
> Localized resource for token 'Direction' could not be found for file
>   with path: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\Template\Features\MyWebPart_MyPart
>   WebPart\MyShortcuts\schema.xml".  5be2859c-93a0-e0a4-d8bc-bbc416633918

The wsp contains 1 feature and 1 listinstance (rootwebonly='true') and 1 webpart. On activating the feature, the list gets created on the root web and webpart is added to the custom webparts.

This works good on the Dev Environment. What could be issue with LIVE?

**UPDATE**

The list schema.xml code (autogenerated):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="MyNewList" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/MyNewList" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>


    <ContentType ID="0x0100b4e36f6692f14571a6834abc75af286d" Name="ListFieldsContentType"><FieldRefs><FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" /><FieldRef ID="{c29e077d-f466-4d8e-8bbe-72b66c5f205c}" Name="URL" /><FieldRef ID="{305bf797-14b5-4a3b-b411-2353cb5e3afc}" Name="Archived" /></FieldRefs></ContentType><ContentTypeRef ID="0x01">
        <Folder TargetName="Item" />
      </ContentTypeRef><ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" /></ContentTypes>
    <Fields>

    <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Title;" Required="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" MaxLength="255" /><Field ID="{c29e077d-f466-4d8e-8bbe-72b66c5f205c}" Name="URL" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="URL" Group="$Resources:core,Base_Columns;" Type="URL" DisplayName="$Resources:core,URL;" Required="TRUE" /><Field Name="Archived" ID="{305bf797-14b5-4a3b-b411-2353cb5e3afc}" DisplayName="Archived" Type="Boolean" /></Fields>
    <Views>


    <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>

        <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu"></FieldRef></ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>

          <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef></OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_ONET_HOME)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View><View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>

        <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef><FieldRef Name="URL" /><FieldRef Name="Archived" /></ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>

          <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef></OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View></Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

On dev as well as live environment, the List gets created. We can add data into the list. But the webpart wont appear? Webpart has code to query this list. There is no exception in the webpart code, but there is some "resources" error in ULS as pasted above.

Comment: Are you provisioning resource files? If yes give details of how have you provisioned that in your solution.

Comment: i did not get you. its a simple webpart. The feature contains a listinstance and webpart. It is deployed to the sitecolelction level. We add it to a page. The webpart queries list and displays data. But cannot see it on LIVE.

Comment: Are you reading from resource files in your code?

Comment: Try in powershell net stop sptimerv4, then net start sptimerv4, then iisreset. If still not possible to read the resource file, it is missing from the solution

Comment: We are not reading nay resource file. Its just a simple webpart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no resources file specified in the call to the some resource key in your web part, SharePoint will look in the default places where you can place your resources files in the following order (given that your language is US-English).

You must check all resources strings in your web part also ULS should have some string like "Localized resource for token 'your resource key' could not be found for file with path: "...

There are 2 options to fix this problem.

1. Make sure that in your resources file, Resources.resx (with its
   variants of languages that you want), there is a "Direction"
   Key defined. (Possible values: LTR, RTL, none)
2. Fill the "DefaultResourceFile" property of your Feature with the
   name of the file of Resources that you want to use. This file must
   be in the path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web
   Server Extensions\14\Resources

Comment: what is this resourse file and where to look for it?

Comment: Your resource file must be at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Resources\{your feature name}\{your resource name}. Check ULS first to get what exactly key is not found.

Comment: the feature has a webpart as well as a list. Is that the cause of the error?

Comment: Yep the list do this. Change the generated Schema.xml file. In the example given it would be: Your resource key name= "$Resources: core, 'Your resource key name';" In this way, we indicate that the 'Your resource key name' is in the file Core.resx (in the 14\Resources, it’s the default SharePoint resources file)

Comment: Check all resources ($Resources:) in your schema of the list. It seems your environments have different core resource files. Or your list schema have resource string that exists only in one environment.

Comment: @AndreyUngur but if the problem is with list schema how would he get error on that webpart page?

Comment: @Unnie, there is no error on webpart page, the error is in ULS; On the webpart page, the webpart doesnot appear.

Comment: @variable then andrey  point is very valid..in the schema of list ,resource file reference might be present.

Comment: Yes it is, can you tell me what I have to do with it? It did not cause any problems on the Dev env.

Comment: I have updated question with the schema.xml code. This was autogenerated.

Comment: @AndreyUngur If all this is OK then, maybe, is the error because dev SP is installed as US and maybe LIVE SP is installed as UK? Or because DEV and LIVE PC have different regional settings?

Comment: Please try to change Direction="$Resources:Direction;" to  Direction="$Resources: core, Direction;" in your schema xml. And check that in your C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Resources\core.resx is 'Direction' key. And yes the problem could be if you have different locale installed in Prod.

Comment: What about setting Direction="None" or "LTR". Is that a better solution?

Comment: You can do this but it's best to get it in resource file for future enhancements