# Issue with List schema : What is Direction?

Tags: list

List.Direction property

Gets or sets a value that specifies the reading order of the list.

It must conform to the following ABNF: Direction = “NONE” | “LTR” | “RTL”.

I would like to know the exact meaning of direction. Because this may help to solve this issue: [Webpart cannot be seen on page after adding. Error in ULS. Feature (wsp) = Webpart+ListInstance](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95898/webpart-cannot-be-seen-on-page-after-adding-error-in-uls-feature-wsp-webpa)

Reference: http://joost.haneveer.nl/sharepoint/localized-resource-for-token-direction-could-not-be-found/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms415091%28v=office.14%29.aspx) documentation says the following

> Direction, Required Text. Specifies the direction of the reading order
>   for the list. Possible values include RTL (right-to-left), LTR
>   (left-to-right), or none.

Languags can be Right-To-Left, like arabic and Left-To-Right Languages like english.
This can have an impact on things like sorting, filtering etc.

Comment: what is none???

Comment: I guess sharepoint determines what it is.